# Resampling with MSB operation

Tags: verilog, sampling, sample-and-hold

I'm new to verilog and HDL, so please be patient with me.

In a code, I have an input variable `clk`, two input 16 bit samples, that are stored into `[31:16] ddc_out_sample` and `[15:0] ddc_out_sample` and an input strobe called `ddc_out_strobe`.

What I want to do is take the 8 MSB bit of `[31:16] ddc_out_sample` and `[15:0] ddc_out_sample`, having a 16 bit sample instead of a 32 one. Then combine 4 of those samples to feed them directly to the output `[31:0] bb_sample`. The output strobe is `bb_strobe`.

I had thought of the following implementation to achieve this:

```
reg count = 0;

always @(posedge clk)
     i_msb <= ddc_chain_out[31:24]
     q_msb <= ddc_chain_out[15:8]
     assign bb_strobe = 1'b0;
     if(count % 4 == 3) 
        assign bb_strobe = ddc_out_strobe;
     end
     count = count + 1;
end
```

I know that asynchronous conditions should be [avoided](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/fpga/synchronisation/), but I don't see how to implement this otherwise.

Any comments and thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Don't mix = and <=, they have different meanings and some tools will object.

2) "assign" is basically wiring one thing to another, it should not be used in "always" blocks.

3) You've not assigned `bb_sample`.

My version:

```
// 'reg' by itself is a single bit, need two bits for 0-3
reg [1:0] count = 0;

always @(posedge clk)
   if (ddc_out_strobe) begin
     i_msb <= ddc_chain_out[31:24];
     q_msb <= ddc_chain_out[15:8];
     if(count == 2'd3) 
         bb_strobe <= 1'b1;
         count <= 2'b0;
     end
     else begin
         count <= count + 1;
         bb_strobe <= 1'b0;
     end
   end
   else begin
      bb_strobe <= 1'b0;
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!
Assigning `bb_sample` could be done by something like `bb_sample <= [31:0]{i_msb,q_msb,bb_sample}`? What I am aiming for there, is to store the newest samples there, disregarding the parts of bb_sample that I no longer need (not sure if that syntax is allowed though...)

Comment: `bb_sample <= {i_msb,q_msb,bb_sample[31:16]}` would be valid; tragically you can't do subselects off anything that isn't a `reg` or `wire`.

Comment: And how about when `ddc_out_strobe`, `bb_sample`, `ddc_chain_out` and `bb_strobe` are `wire`s?
I know that `wire` elements cannot be used as the left-hand side of an `=` or `<=` sign in an `always@` block. But how to assign them if that is now allowed?